# Create tables with MySQL Connector and for loop

Tags: python, loops, mysql-connector, database-cursor

Learning Python:

I have a set of .sql files and try to use a for loop to execute their code (every file contains a drop-table and a create-table statement)

I am using a class which has various methods to execute actions.

this is the error i get for every iteration except the first one (the first iteration seems to work fine)

`2014 (HY000): Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`
I kinda suspect it has something to do with the cursor, but after hours i am still not sure what the problem is...

and this is my code

```
import re
import datetime
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


class Migrator:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password, database, port):
        self.database = {
            'host': host,
            'user': user,
            'password': password,
            'database': database,
            'port': port
        }
        self.db_connection = self.db_connect()
        # here i store the cursor
        self.db_cursor = self.db_connection.cursor()

    def __del__(self):
        self.db_connection.close()

    files_tables = {
        'X00': 'table1_x00',
        'X01': 'table2_x01',
        'X02': 'table3_x02',
        'X03': 'table4_x03',
        'X04': 'table5_x04',
    }

    # connect to db
    def db_connect(self):
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
                host=self.database['host'],
                user=self.database['user'],
                password=self.database['password'],
                database=self.database['database'],
                port=self.database['port']
            )
            if connection.is_connected():
                db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
                print("Connected to MYSQL Server version ", db_Info)
                cursor = connection.cursor()
                cursor.execute("select database();")
                record = cursor.fetchone()
                print("Successfully connected to database: ", record)

                return connection

        except Error as e:
            print('Error while connecting to MySQL', e)

        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=self.database['host'],
            user=self.database['user'],
            password=self.database['password'],
            database=self.database['database'],
            port=self.database['port']
        )
        return mydb

    def read_filelist(self, path):
        '''This method reads out all files and returns their names in a list'''
        onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
        onlyfiles_sorted = sorted(onlyfiles)
        return onlyfiles_sorted

    def create_table_all(self, path):
        '''This creates all the tables without they relationships to other tables'''
        errors = 0
        filelist = self.read_filelist(path)

        for file in filelist:
            f = open(path + "/" + file)
            sql = f.read()
            f.close()

            try:
                self.db_cursor.execute(sql)
            except mysql.connector.Error as e:
                print(e)




test_instance = Migrator('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'test', 'test_database', 3308)
# this is the folder which contains the files 
test_instance.create_table_all('../../../../build/entity_tables_create_only')
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `multi=True` to your execute?

Comment: ty, i tried, unfortunately this didnt work either